# How do I use a django join to select customer_name for every id that is returned in a result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've been looking into django joins, and I can see how I can select related fields with .select_related but I can't seem to get it to work how I want. I basically have summary tables that are linked to the customers table with customer_id FK's, I want to select the customer name from the customers field for every value returned for each of the summaries.

I included pseudo code to show what im trying to do.

```
sql would be = ''' select a.customer_name, b.vm_name, b.vm_cpu, b.vm_mem from customers a, vms b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id'''
```

how do I do that with django. That way when I loop through the returned values

```
for value in sql:
    list.append(value.1, value.2, value.3)
```

that way I can associate and output the customer_name with each field.

Heres what I'm trying to do:

```
 compute_usages_related = ComputeUsages.objects.filter(customer_id = customer_id).filter(load_date = datetime(year, day, selected_month)).select_related('customer_name')
 test_related = []
 for row in compute_usages_related:
    test_related.append(row.customer_name)
```

obviously that doesn't work.

basically that one is for specific customers, but there is a case where company employees with admin rights can query the entire database for all customers and create a usage report so I need to associate customer_names with the query.

Any ideas on how to do this with django?

Models:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inactive = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'customers'

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return self.customer_name

    def clean(self):
      if self.inactive != 'Y' and self.inactive != 'N':
         raise ValidationError('Please enter a Y or N')

class ComputeUsages(models.Model):
    compute_usage_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers)
    vm_name = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    vm_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    core_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    ram_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    guest_os = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    provisioned_cores = models.BigIntegerField()
    provisioned_ram = models.BigIntegerField()
    load_date = models.DateField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'compute_usages'

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return self.vm_name
```

Comment: You should show the models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman doneski, please let me know what you think. I'm trying to follow documentation but its not super clear on this subject.

Comment: I'm fairly sure as I loop through the returned compute usages i could fectch the customer id by the returned id in the row, but I want to do it the django way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *already* do the following, without any use of `select_related`:

```
test_related.append(row.customer.customer_name)
```

because that just uses the fields you have already defined. However, that is pretty inefficient as it is, as it generates a new database query for every row. All `select_related` does is pre-cache that value by doing a JOIN to the Customer table. Again, note that it is the table you are querying, not the column:

```
compute_usages_related = ComputeUsages.objects....select_related('customer')
```

(where I've removed the filter clauses for clarity). And, again, the way to access the column *does not change*: you still do `row.customer.customer_name`, it's just that that no longer does an extra db query.

This would all be a lot clearer for you if you started thinking in terms of models as classes, rather than as SQL queries. Plus, you should really take advantage of the Python shell to explore the attributes of your objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying to read through the docs to get a handle but its a bit daunting. You just helped me out tremendously. Thank you.